# "Broken" regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.2

I have regular expression for parsing many values like `a=b c=d e=f` which should result in dictionary like this: `{'a': 'b', 'c':'d', 'e':'f'}`. I wanted user to allow escaping values using `\` so instead of really simple regexp I've used `((?:[^\\\s=]+|\\.)+)` plus I've added `(?:^|\s)` and `(?=\s|$)` so expression wouldn't match partial results.

```
>>> import re
>>> reg = re.compile(r'(?:^|\s)([\w\d]+)=((?:[^\\\s=]+|\\.)+)(?=\s|$)')
>>> s = r'a=b c=d e=one\two\three'
>>> reg.findall(s)
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'one\\two\\three')]
```

But then someone came along and inserted `=` into right side of the thing.

```
>>> s = r'a=b c=d e=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\cccc
    ccccc=dddddddddddddddd\eeeeeeeeeeeeeee'    
>>> reg.findall(s)
```

And script was stuck on this line (I've waited for several hours and it didn't finish).

**Question**: is this that poor regular expression (why? how would you wrote it?) or is it regexp implementation bug?

*Note: I'm not asking for solutions for this issue, I'm curious **why** `findall()` doesn't finish in few hours.*

Comment: Why don't you allow `=` on the right side of `=`, when you delimiter is the space character?

Comment: @DavidFoerster that was a mistake (which is already fixed). I'm interested why the `findall` never finishes.

Comment: The real qustion is “Why do you have such an awful format”? Use JSON, YAML, newline-separated key=value pairs, whatever!

Comment: @kirelagin Third party application. Can't do a thing about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you nest repetitions and the re-engine seems to try all possible distributions among them:

```
r'(?:^|\s)([\w\d]+)=((?:[^\\\s=]+|\\.)+)(?=\s|$)'
                                ^     ^
```

Better:

```
r'(?:^|\s)([\w\d]+)=((?:[^\\\s=]|\\.)+)(?=\s|$)'
```

In fact the findall would finish (or run out of memory). You can try this with

```
s = r'a=b c=d e=aaaaaaa\bbbbbbbb\ccccccccc=ddddddddd\eeeee'
```

and then successively adding characters after "`e=`"

Comment: Curious. I was expecting regexp to handle situation like this.

Comment: @Vyktor Than you should definitely read the book called “Mastering Regular Expression”. It's fantastic.

Comment: @Vyktor Read up on [Catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions aren't the right tool for your task beyond very simple cases. You need to tokenize the input string.

In simple cases you can use `str.split()`:

```
for tok in s.split(" "):
    tok = tok.split("=", 1)
    key = tok[0]
    value = tok[1]
```

I haven't written python in quite some time, so I'm not sure whether the `for … in …` statement is correct, but you get what I mean.

Comment: You're totatlly right about not using regexps in this case, but your solution doesn't have escapes.

Comment: No, there can be `\ ` (escaped space), therefore I can't use tokenizing. Or at least not this simple implementation.

Comment: I'm aware, that my example doesn't allow escaping – therefore "in simple cases". It was just to illustrate my idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> reg = re.compile(r'(\w+)=(\S+)')
>>> dict(reg.findall(r'a=b c=d e=one\two\three'))
{'e': 'one\\two\\three', 'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
>>> dict(reg.findall(r'a=b c=d e=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\ccccccccc=dddddddddddddddd\eeeeeeeeeeeeeee'))
{'e': 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\\bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\\ccccccccc=dddddddddddddddd\\eeeeeeeeeeeeeee', 'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
```